# Location String Munging in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, split

(Python 2.7, using datasets from http://www.policemisconduct.net/databases/, 2009, 2010)

[[YOU CAN SKIP DOWN TO ____ IF YOU DON'T CARE ABOUT NATURE OF MY DATA]]

I'm fairly new to Python and programming in general - I'd like someone to explain the results I'm getting from my loop.

I'm trying to loop through the 'location' column of a police misconduct dataset.  Its format is as follows:

city, state, USA

(I'm aware the URL above has the data broken into separate 2009 and 2010 files, where the location is already in 2 separate columns, as well as a Google Fusion to which I am referring. This question is specifically about how to make A look like B, as well as the errors I'm throwing and why.)

---

Allow me a simplified version of my question.  Consider the following five locations in  test.csv:

```
Tallahassee, Florida, USA
Denver, Colorado, USA
Watertown, New York, USA
Kalamazoo, Michigan, USA
Toronto, Ontario, Canada
```

I run the follow script:

```
def censor(text, word):
    texts = str(text)
    words = texts.split() #creates the list
    x = "" * len(word) #creates the stars with correct length
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i] == word: 
            words[i] = x #replace
    return "".join(words)

places = pd.read_csv(test.csv) #the 5-place list above
censor(places,"USA")
```

And get the following

```
'Tallahassee,Florida,0Denver,Colorado,1Watertown,NewYork,2Kalamazoo,Michigan,3Toronto,Ontario,Canada'
```

Obviously, the numbers shouldn't be there; it's one big long string (but an array [] instead of "" string throws errors when trying to use the .split method...); Even the spaces I want were dropped.

Adding an alpha character in the return line ""string.join(words) as I tinkered made me even more confused about the loop I had written... (so now line 8 reads: 'return "a".join(words)')

'Tallahassee,aFlorida,aa0aDenver,aColorado,aa1aWatertown,aNewaYork,aa2aKalamazoo,aMichigan,aa3aToronto,aOntario,Canada'

...and the only thing that does well is make me sound like Luigi when I read it.

How can I make a) a two, separate nx1 arrays, where n is the number of observations in each array for State and City, and b) one nX2 array with analogous columns...

Thanks! (And sorry for n3wb? :(

Comment: What is `word`?  The input to your function, where does that come from?

Comment: apologies, @Luigi - it'sa edited.

Comment: @Canuckish Can you add what the csv looks like?

Comment: @Canuckish the numbers are part of the string representation of the dataframe. The replacement works (all the `'USA'`s are gone!), but why not process the dataframe instead of a string?

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Canuckish go read [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe)

Comment: @ToClickorNottoClick http://imgur.com/3TsIUO8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to process this as a string, there's a much easier way to do your "censorship".  You can use the `replace` method of a string to remove all instances of "USA" (or any other substring for that matter).

```
f = open('places.csv')
text = str(f.read())
f.close()
places = text.replace(', USA','')
```

It's then very simple to recreate your dataframe using string operations:

```
t1 = places.split('\n')
t2 = [p.replace(' ','').strip() for p in t1]
final_places = [p.split(',') for p in t2]
```

This gives you a result in array form (**fixed**):

```
[['Tallahassee', 'Florida'], ['Denver', 'Colorado'], ['Watertown', 'NewYork'], ['Kalamazoo', 'Michigan'], ['Toronto', 'Ontario', 'Canada']]
```

To get cities/states:

```
cities = [p[0] for p in final_places]
states = [p[1] for p in final_places]
```

Comment: can you illuminate me on what the .strip() function is doing? If I do this a second time, splitting each element on , could I make 2 separate lists for city and state?

(and as an academic point, why does my original loop put 'aa'__'a' around the numbers in the string representation @jonsharpe mentioned?)

Comment: Stripping removes whitespace (spaces) from the beginning and end of a string.  Where I use it, it is on each city-state pair. I'll edit my answer to show you how to get city/state lists.  Your original loop put 'a's in because it was adding them between empty strings (caused by this: `x = "" * len(word)` not doing what you thought.  try that in a console)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this.

```
def censor_word(word, word_to_censor):
    word = word.strip()
    if word.lower() == word_to_censor.lower():
        return '*' * len(word)
    else:
        return word

def censor(line, word_to_censor):
    words = str(line).split(',') #creates the list
    words = [censor_word(w, word_to_censor) for w in words]
    return ", ".join(words)

with open("test.csv", "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(censor(line, "USA"))
```

Sorry, I have to run out the door.  Usually I explain the code but cannot right now.  If you have questions, I *will* answer them later.

Comment: so after running your script, if I run `censor("USA, USA, USA this is a TEST!", "USA")` it returns `'***, ***, USA this is a TEST!'` 

it seems to be working when I feed it the places list, though...why does it miss that last USA?

Comment: This code is designed to only censor words that match.  It splits the input line on commas, and strips off extra white space (spaces), and then censors only matches.  So, for example, if you had the string "USA Virgin Islands" it wouldn't match and wouldn't censor.  If you want to censor anything that contains the string "USA" you could change it to `if "USA" in word:` but beware, that would also censor anything containing "USA" like "SUSAN".